# after migrate magento website to godaddy server i am unable to edit anything

Tags: magento-1.9

I have migrate my website to godaddy server after migration i am unable to edit any thing in this website & unable to process product order.

Please provide me help to resolve this issue

Comment: This place is to answer your question, what's your question? You need to provide more details, what you can't edit, where etc.